# rule for "-1/∞" when calculating limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I know that there is a rule for "1/∞" saying it is 0.
Is there a rule for negative numbers as well? Is this valid solution?:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}\right)=\frac{-1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2-1}+n)}=\frac{-1}{\infty}=0$$

Comment: Why not try to prove it?

Comment: Not exactly valid because one of the limits in your equation does not exist

Comment: The rule cannot be applied as the denominator does not diverge to infinity. Check your calculations

Comment: To answer the question at hand, recall that constants can be moved through limits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct but the exact reasoning is not.

If you believe that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n} = 0 $$

then try this
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}=-\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}\right) = -0 = 0$$

This is valid because constants can be pulled outside of limits.

Comment: Note that the limit of a ratio is only equal to the ratio of limits if both numerator and denominator converge. In this example, the denominator does not converge.